# named scope - wrong number of bind variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following named scope:

```
named_scope :report_search, lambda { |search|
  {
    :conditions => ["rep_name like ? or rep_id like ? or rep_symbol like ? or rep_issue like ?", search]
  }
}
```

When i run it, I get the error message:

```
wrong number of bind variables
```

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me figure out wht's wrong with the code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need one variable for each question mark in your bind statement. If they're all the same, you need to repeat them multiple times:

```
named_scope :report_search, lambda { |search|
  {
    :conditions => ["rep_name like ? or rep_id like ? or rep_symbol like ? or rep_issue like ?", search, search, search, search]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is there any other way of performing the 'or' condition without repeating the argument?

Comment: Kandada beat me to the punch. That's how you would do it with only repeating it once.

Answer (score 24):

You can use named bind variables if you don't want to repeat the input.

```
named_scope :report_search, lambda { |search|
  {
    :conditions => ["  rep_name   LIKE :search OR 
                       rep_id     LIKE :search OR 
                       rep_symbol LIKE :search OR 
                       rep_issue  LIKE :search", :search => search]
  }
}
```